# For the first time button click it is not binding data into table,

Tags: javascript

For the first time button click it is not binding data into table, again after second click it is getting bound. I need the data to be bound for first click

```
var resturant=angular.module('resturantmodule',[]);
resturant.controller('resturantcontroller',function($scope,$http){

    $scope.resturants=[];
    $scope.onResturantClick=function(){

        var url="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20local.search%20where%20zip='"+$scope.pin +"'and%20query='"+$scope.order +"'&format=json&diagnostics=false&callback=";

        $http.get(url).success(function(data){
        $scope.resturants.push(data);


        if(data){

            var len = data.query.results.Result.length;           
            var txt = "";
            if(len > 0){                 
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){

                    if(true){                    
                        txt += "<tr><td>"+data.query.results.Result[i].Title+"</td><td>"+data.query.results.Result[i].Title+"</td></tr>";                      

                    }
                }               
                if(txt != ""){          


                    var tbody = document.querySelector("#list tbody");                    
                    tbody.appendChild(tbody.innerHTML=txt);
                   // tbody.innerHTML=txt;
                    //alert(txt);
                    //tr.innerHTML = txt;
                   // tbody.appendChild(tbody)


                }
            }
        }

        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

by using below functions we can bind data from javascript to html table

var tbody = document.querySelector("#list tbody");   //Add Table ID 
tbody.appendChild(tbody.innerHTML=txt);